# MailFred Issue Emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently changed the security in my Google settings and I keep getting an email that starts with the following sentence:

"Your script, MailFred 1.145, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here."

When I click there all I get is a 404 Forbidden page. Back in the email text there is a long list of when the script has failed. I am not sure how to fix this issue, but I would like to stop getting the emails.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: **I don't know what worked, but I am no longer receiving the emails** Thank you so much for all of your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Google Accounts Settings and under Security, click the Apps and Websites link.

Here you'll see a list of all scripts that have access to your Google Account. Revoke access to the one that is sending those error notifications.

Comment: That's the thing, I already have. I started getting these messages after I revoked permission for MailFred 1.145

Answer (score 0):

You're right in your comment : revoking authorization while letting the script run is the origin of the error and the subsequent errors notifications...

I don't know the MailFred app but from what I saw on their site it's all built using Google-Apps-Script so I guess the trigger they use must appear as any other one...

To disable this triggers that is trying to run , follow these simple steps :

- open any Google Spreadsheet, document or form
- then open the script editor (from the "tools" menu),
- go to 'resources' > triggers > all your triggers
- and there delete the trigger(s) that you don't want to run.

If you see many of them, try to determine which one belongs to this app... you can check the notification mode, set it to a known time and wait for the next email, see at what time it was sent... The method is not very acurate  (about an hour time frame) but it can help.
[image]

Sorry I can't be more concise, I don't use this app and didn't find a lot of informations about it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that, there was only one trigger. Hopefully that will solve the problem!

Comment: Don't forget to come back to tell us if it did:-)

Comment: Sadly it did not. I appreciate your help though. I still got the email last night about it. The frustrating thing is that it won't go away, but also that I don't use Chrome.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work... unfortunately I don't have any other suggestion.Maybe you should try to contact the developers?

Comment: No worries! I will try to contact them, I just haven't had as much time to mess around with it as I would have liked. I appreciate your suggestions! I will keep trying and if I find something that works I will definitely let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how I did it. It's a pretty straight forward according to me.
See the following message I got when my script fails. It says,

"Your script, clearContent, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, **click here**."

You should be getting the same kind of message. Click on "click here" hyper linked text, it will directly take you to the settings page of that trigger. And, just change the setting of the particular trigger or delete it.

Comment: When I click on the "Click Here" I get an error page. The 403 Forbidden page.

Comment: @Sarah After trying all the approaches if you are still getting the emails for summary of failure for your MailFred 1.145 script, I would request you to file a bug at [google-apps-script-issue-tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues).